# PHP submitted form response is not showing up on the same page

Tags: php, jquery

My PHP form is functioning well, responses are showing up when the preventDefault is not in use (without jQuery script), but with the script in place, no responses are showing, however the page stays in place. 
You can have a look at the project I'm working on: www.designbynoemi.co.uk

Here is my markup:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
        <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
        </p>
        <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p class="form-group contact-submit">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary submit">
        </p>
        <div id="response">

        </div>
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
/*
* Contact Form Class
*/

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$admin_email = 'contact@designbynoemi.co.uk'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
        $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check message length
        if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }
    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
             "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

and now my script - which is causing the problem:

```
<script>
     $("#contact-form").submit(function(event) 
     {
         /* stop form from submitting normally */
         event.preventDefault();

         /* get some values from elements on the page: */
         var $form = $( this ),
             $submit = $form.find( 'input[name="submit"]' ),
             name_value = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
             email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
             message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
             url = $form.attr('action');

         /* Send the data using post */
         var posting = $.post( url, { 
                           name: name_value, 
                           email: email_value, 
                           message: message_value 
                       });

         posting.done(function( data )
         {
             /* Put the results in a div */
             $( "#response" ).html(data);

             /* Change the button text. */
             $submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

             /* Disable the button. */
             $submit.attr("disabled", true);
         });
    });
</script>
```

It might be something really simple, but it's nearly 03:00 am here and I would really appreciate some help now...

Comment: which part of the `and now my script - which is causing the problem:` is causing the problem?

Comment: the problem is: no responses are showing up. I do understand that preventDefault is preventing a new URL load and this is what I'm after. But  how do I get my form responses back?

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with preventDefault. What I'm trying to do is to show all responses on the same page without sending user to another page.But no responses are showing up now.

Comment: I'm afraid no errors are showing up in the console either.

Comment: `console.log(data);` put this line in your `posting.done` method and provide me the output in the console